# Set of vector projection and linear independence.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Determine for which vectors $u, v$ the set below is linearly independent.
$\{\operatorname{proj}_u(v), \operatorname{perp}_u(v)\}$?

$\operatorname{proj}_u(v)$ : Projection of $v$ onto $u$

$\operatorname{perp}_u(v)$ : Projection of $v$ perpendiular to $u$.

I don't know how to start.
Can you explain the question to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Two vectors are linearly independent" $\iff$ "one vector is not a scalar multiple of the other"

By definition, $proj_u(v)+perp_u(v)=v$ and $proj_u(v) \perp perp_u(v)$. The only way two orthogonal vectors could be the same up to a scalar multiple is if one of them is the zero vector. In that case, $v$ is a) either a scalar multiple of $u$, or b) is orthogonal to $u$. In any other case, you will have linear independence.